# Groovy Builder support

Tags: groovy, closures, dsl

How can i build the above pattern using groovy builder support

```
emp = empFileFactory.root()
{
  emp(id: '3', value: '1')

  emp(id:'24')
  {
    emp(id: '1', value: '2')
    emp(id: '6', value: '7')
    emp(id: '7', value: '1')
  }

  emp(id: '25')
  {
    emp(id: '1', value: '1')
    emp(id: '6', value: '7')
  }

}
```

i'm trying to build the above strucutre in groovy can some one explain how could i acieve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this (this has no error handling, and just returns null for methods that I don't expect to be called):

```
// First define our class to hold our created 'Emp' objects
@groovy.transform.Canonical
class Emp {
  String id
  String value
  List<Emp> children = []
}

class EmpBuilder extends BuilderSupport{
  def children = []
  protected void setParent(Object parent, Object child){
    parent.children << child
  }
  protected Object createNode(Object name){
    if( name == 'root' ) {
      this
    }
    else {
      null
    }
  }
  protected Object createNode(Object name, Object value){
    null
  }
  protected Object createNode(Object name, Map attributes){
    if( name == 'emp' ) {
      new Emp( attributes )
    }
    else {
      null
    }
  }
  protected Object createNode(Object name, Map attributes, Object value){
    null
  }
  protected void nodeCompleted(Object parent, Object node) {
  }
  Iterator iterator() { children.iterator() }
}
```

Then, if we call this with your required builder code like so:

```
b = new EmpBuilder().root() {
  emp(id: '3', value: '1')

  emp(id:'24') {
    emp(id: '1', value: '2')
    emp(id: '6', value: '7')
    emp(id: '7', value: '1')
  }

  emp(id: '25') {
    emp(id: '1', value: '1')
    emp(id: '6', value: '7')
  }
}
```

We can print out the 'tree' like so

```
b.each { println it }
```

and see we get the structure we asked for:

```
Emp(3, 1, [])
Emp(24, null, [Emp(1, 2, []), Emp(6, 7, []), Emp(7, 1, [])])
Emp(25, null, [Emp(1, 1, []), Emp(6, 7, [])])
```

Comment: for printing the tree do i have to issue db.each {println it}

Comment: yup...  I forgot to paste that bit in to the answer :-/

Comment: when should code will come to else if( name == 'root' ) {
      this 
    }

Comment: this line: `b = new EmpBuilder().root() {`

Comment: no the method protected Object createNode(Object name, Map attributes) has one check  else if( name == 'root' ) { this }

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry that was a mistake on my part... removed it from the code above...

Comment: the second question how can i traverse to this tree

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement extend the [`BuilderSupport`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/BuilderSupport.html) class, which is pretty easy to do. There's [a pretty nice tutorial here](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=296081).

You need to implement a few methods, but the naming should be pretty self-explanatory:

- `createNode` creates a node (each node has a name and optional attributes and/or a value)
- `setParent` assigns a node as another nodes parent

That's pretty much it.